# Solution design for a serverless hosted in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm designing a website solution in AWS containing only 2 sites: the main dashboard showing company data in a graph (index site) and single pages for each company.

**Pre-requisites:**

- serverless.
- cost-effective solution based on-demand traffic.
- everything can be publicly accessed. not login required.
- website in HTML using JS.
- the data is changed 1 time per day.

**Functionalities:**

- Main dashboard (a graph in JS) reading dynamic data (last 30 reports). The data can be read from a file: txt, json or maybe a database: dynamoDB. As it has 
  to be publicly accessed, I don't think using a database will be a
  good strategy.
- Company page.The users can publicly post comments and rate with starts.

**How do you personally would design this solution?**

My first approach is: dashboard site reading data from a txt file, company site use a DynamoDB to save/show comments and ratings.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/building-a-serverless-web-app-on-aws-services

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/

Comment: How often will the dynamic "txt, json or database" data change? I would recommend different designs depending on if it is changing constantly (once a minute for example) or if it is only changing once a day or less.

Comment: The information changes only 1 time per day

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use some kind of "orchestration framework" to launch such services in AWS. Alternatively, you could manually write and manage a Cloudformation template for this purpose.

You should also not worry about keeping each of these components in a seperate git repo. You could also employ different programming language for each component if necessary. This will allow you to design it not only as "serverless" but also utilizing microservice architecture, which AWS is heavily advancing in the field.

This example should quickstart you: https://serverless.com/examples/aws-node-single-page-app-via-cloudfront/

The static part of your application (HTML + JS) should rely on API's to gather data.

These API's can be Lamba functions with API Gateway in front of them. That would allow you to securely connect to a database without worrying about security.

This example should quickstart your API part: https://serverless.com/examples/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb-and-offline/

Given how Lambda, S3, and DynamoDB pricing works (large free tiers) this would most likely run for free for the first 50K monthly visitors or so, with approx 2-3EUR p/m for each other 50K monthly visitor increment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do not worry about the deployment with BeanStalk or even CloudFormation (that is not a problem). However, I question myself about the solution you propose. If I would design a solution uploading 1 file per day to S3 (with the information required for the dashboard) I could avoid the need to query dynamodb (API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB).  That should be the most cost-effective way, what do you think?

Comment: I would still use DynamoDB. It is easier to update and maintain, and is almost guaranteed to be easier to implement than manually editing files. It also performs much better with visitors from varied geographic areas than S3 does under load.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how often your data is updated and how real-time your data displaying should be.

If it's just daily updates, and you can afford a few minutes latency in your updates, I would generate static pages with the new data every day using Jekyll (via Siteleaf, for example) or Hugo (which can run on AWS Lambda).

Then, automatically export those pages to an S3 bucket, and cache everything using Cloudfront for better performance and lower costs. Blazing fast, no moving parts, simple to maintain.

If you do need your displayed data to be continuously up-to-date, go with a S3 hosted single-page app fetching your data from a Lambda-DynamoDB based API, fronted by API Gateway.

You could deploy it using the Serverless framework or something similar, which are much more user-friendly than CloudFormation itself.